# How to implement side-popovers as done by Wunderlist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a simple web app. At one part of it, I want to show options related to the selected item. I want it to be similar to what wunderlist has done:

As can be seen is this image, there are two items in a list.

[image]

Selecting an item leads to a popup - from the side:

[image]

I want to add something similar to my site. I know how to have alerts, popups, dialog boxes and models but I do not know how to have this (visible at the right hand side and not center of the screen).

Can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5fLyJ/)

I guess this is what you need. May be you can work on this more,

```
$("#click").click(function () {
    $("#popup").animate({left:"335px"});
});
```

Hope this helps
Thank you